# Laravel Composer Development Packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I've some packages for laravel which are needed only in development. When I create a new project I've to download all of them. Is there any way i can store them somehow or i can type a command and all packages are added to my project.

Comment: [composer install](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install-i) command. Pay attention to use of --dev and --no-dev options and combine those with your development and production environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "download all of them"? Usually, Composer uses a cache on your local system

Answer (score 1):

By default composer is per-project package and dependency manager that puts the packages in the vendor directory of the project but it seems that it allowed to install package globally with global command from COMPOSER_HOME directory like this :

php composer.phar global require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer

for more information i recommend to see the following link from composer site :
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#global

Comment: Yes totally forgot about the global package container. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a default `composer.json` file, or just a part containing the required packages on production and development environments (`require` and `require-dev` sections), then just copy that section to your new project and run `composer install`.
2. You can have a shell file `init.sh` containing the initialization code such as

```
    composer require vendor1/package1 vendor2/package2 vendor3/package3
    composer require vendor4/package4 vendor5/package5 vendor6/package6 --save-dev
```

and then copy that file inside the new project and run `. init.sh` or `sh init.sh`

If the required version is in your composer package cache, it won't be downloaded again, will be used from the cache. If there are any new versions, it'll download the updated package. (If you don't require a specific version while creating the above files)

Comment: Yes if you install it it'll work. Easiest method will be installing Git for Windows application.